# Objects with arrays on a ListView in NativeScript

Tags: lodash, nativescript

I have used _.groupBy from Lodash to arrange an list in categories. How to launch it on a template like this:

```
<ListView items="{{ objectList }}">
  <ListView.itemTemplate>
    <Label text="{{ objectList[0].cat }}" textWrap="true"/>
  </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

or get the keys from the object

```
<ListView items="{{ objectList }}">
  <ListView.itemTemplate>
    <Label text="{{ keys }}" textWrap="true"/>
  </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Please update the example which an example of how your bindingContext object looks. Just console.dir(yourContext) and we'll probably be able to help you better.

Comment: Can you please provide some more code from the js file where you are taking the `objectList` from?